# Ruby iterating array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

I have a JSON data structure like this...

```
{
  "items": [
      {
        "person": { // person hash }
      },
      {
        "dog": { // dog hash }
      },
      {
        "fruit": { // fruit hash }
      },
      {
        “person”: { // person hash }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Each item in the array contains only one key:value pair. The key is the bot that tells me what type of item the value is.

What I'd like to do is iterate the array and run a different function for each type of item.

So I have something like this...

```
items = data.dig('items')

items.map do |item|
  if person = item.dig('person')
    transform_person(person)
  elsif dog = item.dig('dog')
    transform_dog(dog)
  elsif fruit = item.dig('fruit')
    transform_fruit(fruit)
  end
end
```

But I feel like there should be a more elegant way to do this?

Apologies. I appear to have left some ambiguity in my question.

The initial array may contain multiple items with the same key. What I am trying to do is map to an array of items that are transformed into what is required by the front end. The input contains a strange structure and info that is not needed by the front end.

So the output array order must match the input array order.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It's a no-no to change the question after answers have been posted, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @CarySwoveland wtf, lol! That’s the most bizarre thing I’ve ever heard. Of course you can change questions even after answers have been posted. That’s what the edit button is for. Yes, it’s not ideal but i realised that the question needed more info. Lol! You’re a funny guy.

Comment: It's true, I'm funny, but in this instance I'm serious. Changes to questions can and often do render answers incorrect or even nonsensical. All of the answers given here can now be faulted because they don't address your edit, but most readers will not be aware that the edit was done after the answers were posted. The edit button is for clarifying the question, not changing it. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) See the Community Wiki answer (concerning editing questions) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts): "You edit to make things better, clearer, more effective -- *never to change meaning* [my emphasis]." That pertains to anyone editing a question, including the asker. Aside: your antepenultimate paragraph needs clarification. (I would have mentioned that even if I didn't have the opportunity to use that word.)

Comment: I did clarify the question. I have asked people to make bigger changes to their own questions after answering them myself. In the 8 years I’ve been using StackOverflow I’ve never heard any such rule about editing questions. Sorry you didn’t like the edit. But what option was there? Leave it here and not get an answer to the question I wanted? Delete it in order to replicate it and add a sentence to the end? I get that you shouldn’t ask a question and then change it to something entirely unrelated (I have seen that before) but that is not what I’ve done.

Answer (score 2):

First you'll want to define the key preference in a constant:

```
PECKING_ORDER = %w[ person dog fruit ]
```

Then you can use that to find it:

```
def detect(item)
  PECKING_ORDER.lazy.map do |key|
    [ key, item.dig(key) ]
  end.find do |key, v|
    v
  end
end
```

Where that can dig up the first item that's found. `lazy` is used here so it doesn't dig them all up needlessly, just does them one at a time until there's a hit.

This gives you a key/value pair which you can use with dynamic dispatch:

```
items.each do |item|
  key, value = detect(item)

  if (key)
    send(:"transform_#{key}", value)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi. I have cleared up some ambiguity in my question. Sorry for the ambiguous question in the first place.

Comment: thanks. Will have a look tomorrow and try to implement it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

if you know the mapping, you could make a pseudo factory hash:

```
methods_mapped = {
  "person" => ->(person) { do_something_with_person(person) },
  "dog" => ->(dog) { do_something_with_dog(dog) },
  "fruit" => ->(fruit) { do_something_with_fruit(fruit) }
}

items.map do |item|
  key = item.keys.first # what if keys.size > 1 ?
  method = methods_mapped.fetch(key)
  method.call(item[key])
end
```

or you could it from the opposite direction:

```
methods_mapped.each do |key, method|
  method.call(items.dig(key))
end
```

Comment: I like this idea (if I don’t fully understand it). I will have a look tomorrow to have a go at it. Thanks.

Comment: did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Let `f` be a given method that takes as an argument a hash. Without loss of generality, suppose it is as follows. This corresponds to the OP's `transform_person`, `transform_dog` and `transform_fruit` methods combined.

```
def f(h)
  case h.keys.first
  when :person then "somebody"
  when :dog    then "doggie" 
  when :fruit  then "juicy"
  end
end
```

Suppose we are also given (no need for `dig` here)

```
items = data[:items]
  #=> [{:person=>{:name=>"Melba"}},
  #    {:dog=>{:tricks=>[:roll_over, :shake_a_paw]}},
  #    {:fruit=>{:good=>"raspberries"}}]
```

and

```
key_order = [:bird, :marsupial, :dog, :person]
```

We wish to find the first element `k` of `key_order` for which `items` contains a hash `h` for which `h.key?(k) #=> true`. If such a hash `h` is found we are to then execute `f(h)`.

First compute a hash `key_map`.

```
key_map = items.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g.keys.first] = g }
  #=> {:person=>{:person=>{:name=>"Melba"}},
  #    :dog=>{:dog=>{:tricks=>[:roll_over, :shake_a_paw]}},
  #    :fruit=>{:fruit=>{:good=>"raspberries"}}}
```

Then we simply execute

```
k = key_order.find { |k| key_map[k] }
  #=> :dog
k ? f(key_map[k]) : nil
  #=> "doggie"
```

Comment: Excellent. This will take a while to sink in. Haha. I will be giving this a try tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would kept it simple:

```
items.map do |item|
  do_something_with_person(item) if item.dig('person')
  do_something_with_dog(item) if item.dig('dog')
  do_something_with_fruit(item) if item.dig('fruit')
end
```

or

```
items.each do |item|
  case item
    when item.dig('person') then do_something_with_person(item)
    when item.dig('dog') then do_something_with_dog(item)
    when item.dig('fruit') then do_something_with_fruit(item)
  end
end
```

or

```
def do_something(item)
  case
    when item.dig('person') then do_something_with_person(item)
    when item.dig('dog') then do_something_with_dog(item)
    when item.dig('fruit') then do_something_with_fruit(item)
  end
end
items.map { |item| do_something(item) }
```

Comment: The first continues to execute after  `item.dig(...)` is `true`. Why `item.dig` rather than simply `item.key?(...)`?